# Submitting Hugo Form As JSON/TOML/YAML

Tags: json, yaml, hugo, toml

I'm trying to create a website that has a form that allows people to enter data directly into a json/yaml/toml file (doesn't matter which, I don't have a preference).

It's easy to pull data out of the file to display, but I want people to submit their own information and have it saved to the file.

I don't have any code yet since I'm not even sure where to start on the form. I thought it would be super simple, just create a form and have it submit the data to the file, but I can't find the instructions in my Hugo book or online, here or otherwise.

I'd love some help if anyone has time to give me a hand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hugo is a static website generator. Acting on user-submitted data is a dynamic action. Hugo cannot help you with that. What Hugo does is to create `.html` from your input, and you serve those files with a web server. The files cannot change after they have been created, and Hugo is a processor that is run to create the files, not an active service running when you serve the files. Therefore, you cannot act on user-submitted data.

You either need implement everything client-side via JavaScript (or WASM), or you need to have an active backend to do what you want. In both cases, Hugo cannot help you.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I thought I could make it happen with Node.JS, but I can’t seem to figure out how to write to the JSON file (I know it should be a simple fs.write(), but I’m not sure how to integrate that with Hugo. It’s so simple to read JSON in Hugo, and I get that it’s static, which is the whole point. But it’s just submitting trivial data (no PII or anything) to a json file. I just wish it was simpler.

I figured ajax would work as well, but I’m not really savvy with ajax so I wasn’t sure/where to implement it.

Thank you for your thoughtful reply.

Comment: @T.J. The problem is the timeline: Hugo runs *before* the site is displayed. When the user sees the form and enters something, Hugo's job is already done and it has nothing to do with the site anymore. You can of course have a Node.JS backend and communicate with it via ajax (or rather, `fetch` unless you need to support IE) but Hugo will play no rule in that anymore. If you want Hugo-like templating support at runtime, you can do so by having a Go-based backend and use the `html/template` package that is also used by Hugo.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I was thinking as well, I'm just glad I had someone who knew more confirm it form me. I wish my simple project was simpler!

Comment: @T.J. You can keep the project simple by not using Hugo and instead using a framework for dynamic websites for everything. For a simple project, the performance gain you would have with Hugo for the static parts is not really relevant and the entropy would be significantly smaller if you render everything the same way.